# Option do not show schema names in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I love the fact that tree and list controls in Windows allows incremental searches. Just select a starting point, and type, and the control will select the best matching node for you.

This works in SSMS, but there's an annoying problem, especially so in the table node. SSMS prefixes all table names with the schema name and a dot. To make an incremental search here, I have to type 'dbo.', followed by whatever I'm searching for. Is there an option to turn off this table name representation in SSMS?

I hope I'm asking this on the right stack exchange site. If you feel it's off base, let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no way to customise this. If you have two objects named the same but in different schemas e.g. sales.person, hr.person then there would be no way to distinguish them.

I read yesterday about http://www.sqltreeo.com/wp/ which allows you to customise the tree hierarchy in SSMS. You may want to look in to that tool but I doubt it will let you do it either.

You can however right click and select Filter from the context menu, which is suspect is the closest you can get to this functionality.

Comment: I had not reflected on the fact that SSMS is actually implemented in a Visual Studio shell. As such, it's possible to extend it with add-ins, just like the product you linked to. This gave me an idea to google for SSMS and add-in. I found two really nice sites: http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/ and http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

I'm going to accept your answer, because it led me to something usable (I found a quick-find add-in that looks promising!).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround:**

Tree/List View IntelliSense behavior is available in the "Object Explorer Details" window.

**To Start:**

Click on Object Explorer "Tables" folder.
Click F7 and this will bring up the "Object Explorer Details" window.
This window allows one to use IntelliSense to find the closest match to what is typed in the Tree/List View.

**Lastly:**

Move the "Object Explorer Details" window to the same location as the "Object Explorer" window if this is the position that is preferred.

Comment: I like this solution! 1. It remains there after restarting SSMS. 2. You now have both the treeview option as well as the details view option. The toolbar functionality in the Object explorer Details panel is a bit clunky, but it serves my main purpose.

Answer (score -1):

The current limitation of 2500 items expanded in one Object Explorer Node has been put in place to prevent the Tree View Control from exceeding the 64K limit when multiple Object Explorer nodes get expanded. The Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 version of the Tree View control has a bug where it just stops displaying nodes once the total number of nodes exceeds 64K.

Object Explorer Details window can be used to see the entire list of items - it doesn't have the above limitation. Users can see the list by clicking at the informational node that displays the warning in the Object Explorer. Object Explorer Details duplicates most of Object Explorer functionality including all the context menus.

Good for use:-

1. here is how you fix that, you either press F7 key to display the object explorer details, or from view > Object explorer details
2. I’d also suggest the filter option in the table context menu, since the question explicitly asked how to avoid the Object Explorer Details.